# Sorting vector of arrays by array's element

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, vector

I have encountered a problem when writing algorithm for solving Knapsack problem. I have a vector of 3-element arrays (C++11) and I want to sort the vector by the value of let's say first element of these arrays.

I've tried std::sort with predefined compare function, but it doesn't even compile.

I guess my compare function doesn't work as I expect:

```
bool compareByValue(const data &a, const data &b)
{
    return a[0] < b[0];
}

int main()
{
    vector<array<int, 3> > myVector;
    ...
    sort ( myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), compareByValue );
}
```

It's not the first time when I have the similar problem, I tried to find solution on the Net, but without any satisfying result.

Comment: Post compilation error. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your post doesn't seem to contain a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you got `data` from, but you need to change it to `array<int, 3>` or make `compareByValue` a template:

```
bool compareByValue(const array<int, 3> &a, const array<int, 3>&b)
{
    return a[0] < b[0];
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I just found it somewhere and I didn't notice I have to change that. I'm dumb.

Comment: See the answer from @Mikhail as well. You don't even need your own predicate.

Answer (score 6):

Also note that `std::array` has [overloaded comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp), which compare arrays lexicographically. That means, if you want to sort based on the first element, you don't even need a predicate. Just `std::sort` your vector.