# Get the first five greatest results in an array of vector

Tags: c++

I am working on a CSV file that I got from yahoo finance, which has information about the prices on the stock of AAPL. I am trying to display the first five greatest percent change that increased the most of that file.

for the percent change, I used:

```
s[x].percent_change = (s[x].adj_close2 - s[x].open2) / s[x].open2 * 100;
```

as my formula, which worked.

then I coded this:

```
    double original = s[0].percent_change;
    int maximum = 0;
    //Loop that computes the stock whose percentage change increased the most
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {

        if (s[i].percent_change > original) {
            original = s[i].percent_change;
            maximum = i;
        }

    }
    cout << "\n\nThe greatest percent change is the date: " << endl;
    cout << s[maximum].date << endl;
    cout << s[maximum].adj_close << endl;
    cout << s[maximum].percent_change << endl;
```

which again, worked, to get the stock whose percentage change increased the most

but the thing is, I cannot figure out what to do next after this.

How could I get the other four greatest results of the CSV file? I tried modifying the loop and adding another loop, but those loops did not work.

I am still learning c++, please be as simple as you can.

Comment: It is always polite to include a [mcve] which includes a main() function so that members can compile your code.  Otherwise, we have to write our own main and write our own #include statements if we want to compile your code.

Comment: [std::partial_sort()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) might be useful.

Comment: The MCVE is more than polite. Crafting a MCVE before asking the question very often eliminates the need for the question. MCVE is a powerful debugging technique. When you have a MCVE you have a program that is the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug. It's really easy to see the bug at that point even if you can't figure out how to solve it. Most of the time you don't even get near a full MCVE before the bug reaches out of the code and slaps you in the face.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. It is a naive approach however.

```
double original[5];
for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){ #save the first 5 entries
    original[i] = s[i].percent_change;
}
int maximum[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
//Loop that computes the stock whose percentage change increased the most
for (int i = 5; i < lines; i++) { #we can ignore the first 5 lines here
    for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++) {
        if (s[i].percent_change > original[j]) {
            original[j] = s[i].percent_change;
            maximum[j] = i;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Note that this will fail if you have less than 5 elements in s.

Comment: this actually partially worked, it showed me the second greatest result, but not the other results :(

Comment: If you figure out what the problems was, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is sorting method in  in C++ STL.
So it would be better to use it.
Here is example.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Row {
    float percent_change;
};

bool compareRow(const Row& a, const Row& b) {
    return a.percent_change > b.percent_change;
}

sort(s.begin(), s.end(), compareRow);
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    cout << s[i].percent_change << endl;
}
```

Maybe it would be better to check this page
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-a-vector-in-c/

Comment: should i create a data type for a and b?

Comment: No. Instead you could just use array, but I think it would be better to use struct. Check here for just using array https://stackoverflow.com/a/34220109/11277538

Comment: [std::partial_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) is more appropriate as only the 5 greatest rows are wanted.